# Get csv into pandas dataframe from current date

Tags: python, csv, pandas, timestamp

I have a problem with automatically importing csv and creating pandas dataframe. The code I've got:

```
from datetime import time
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import os
import fnmatch
def get_local_file(pdate, hour, path='/apps/dev_data/data/'):
        """Get date+hour processing file from local drive

       :param pdate: str Processing date
        :param hour: str Processing hour
        :param path: str Path to file location
        :return: Pandas DF Retrieved DataFrame
        """

        sdate = pdate + '-' + str(hour)
        for p_file in os.listdir(path):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(p_file, 'RSRAN098_IP_R*'+sdate+'*.csv'):
                return path+p_file

def get_files(pdate, path='/apps/dev_data/data/'):
    hours = [time(i).strftime('%H') for i in range(24)]
    fileList=[]
    for hour in hours:
        fileList.append(get_local_file(pdate, hour))
    return fileList

processing_date = datetime.strptime('20170614', '%Y%m%d').date()
a = get_files(str(processing_date).replace('-', '_'))
print a
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in a:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0, delimiter=';')
    list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_)
```

The only problem is that I have a fixed date, I can't find a way to put the current date,

Comment: what do you mean by current date? does it mean today's date?

Comment: @AkshayKandul Yes.

Comment: you can use datetime.now().date() instead of datetime.strptime('20170614', '%Y%m%d').date(). This will give you current date or today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get current date with datetime module.
replace this 
`processing_date = datetime.strptime('20170614', '%Y%m%d').date()`
with something like `datetime.datetime.now()`

but I think maybe I don't your point. because the answer seems too straightford.